# Better alternative to @media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I'm using this now,

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) { #icons { border-radius: 0px } }
@media (    width: 1025px) { #icons { border-radius: 1px 1px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1026px) { #icons { border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1027px) { #icons { border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1028px) { #icons { border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1029px) { #icons { border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1030px) { #icons { border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1031px) { #icons { border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1032px) { #icons { border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px } }
@media (    width: 1033px) { #icons { border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px } }
```

To generate a flexible border-radius, proportional to the client's window width. Though, this looks ridiculous.

How else can this be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps use a little dynamic, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) coding with JS?

The following uses jQuery for convenience.

```js
var win = $(window);
win.resize(function() {
  if(win.width() >= 1024) {
    var padding = win.width()-1024;
    $("#icons").css("border-radius", padding + "px " + padding + "px 0px 0px");
  }
}).resize();
```

```css
#icons {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icons">Try resizing the window to widths greater than 1024px.</div>
```

What it does:

1. Caches `$(window)` to avoid multiple DOM queries (which are slow).
2. Every time window resizes, call the function.
3. If window width is in range (> 1024px), run code.
4. Make `border-radius` string by calculating the necessary padding.
5. Trigger function with `resize()` on load.

Comment: I added a closing parenthesis on `line 5`, `$("#icons")...` and error reads `Unexpected string literal " + ". Expected ')' to end a argument list.`

Comment: @zaydek Edited. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks OK. I corrected it but the above error code still reads same message.

Comment: @zaydek Try the entire code again. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: @zaydek I'm glad I helped! Added in a fun little snippet too for your convenience.

Comment: Oh interesting, cool. Thanks! I noticed the if the window is resized too fast, i.e., on a desktop internet client, it doesn't resize. The client applications appears to require some ms to refresh, otherwise it skips.

Answer (score 4):

Media queries are not ridiculous... Using JS to replace them is ridiculuos especially when it's 2016.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) { #icons { border-radius: 0px } }

@media (min-width: 1025px and max-width: 1033px) {
  #icons {
    border-radius: calc(100vw - 1024px) calc(100vw - 1024px) 0px 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1034px) {
  #icons {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: That works well. What about the intended effect of a max `10px border-radius` at `1034+ px` and a min `0px at 1024- px`, so that each `px` from `1024` to `1034` adds a `px` to the `border-radius`?

Comment: well the minimum is already supported by the `max-width: 1024px` rule. Just add another one for `min-width: 1025px`: `@media (min-width: 1025px and max-width: 1034px)` and the third one to have always 10px after 1035px

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not understanding. `@meda (min-width: 1025px) { ... } @media (max-width: 1034px) { ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

Using % instead of px. You may specify the value of border-radius in percentages.

Also you can use Javascript:

```
     bordervalue = window.innerWidth.toString().split('').pop();
     /*here you can modify border value as you wish*/
     document.getElementById("icons").style.borderRadius=bordervalue + "px " + bordervalue + "px 0px 0px";
```

Comment: Example? And a `%` of what? The width? Thanks.

Comment: @zaydek If the width of the browser screen is 1000px and you set a border-radius: 1% 1% 0px 0px, that's equal to border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px. Now, if you want it to be 1px when 1000px, border-radius:0.1% 0.1% 0px 0px, will do. Do you understand it now?

Comment: Somewhat, but I'm aiming for, i.e., 9px at 999px width, so it would require some additional math because. Instead of percentage, it could be something perhaps like pulling the last digit of the width, i.e., 9 in a given range of 990 to 1000. If I'm not misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: @zaydek Check my answer to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Between December 2019 and April 2020 the browsers all added support for a new method in CSS called clamp( ).

Replace media queries with [clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp())

Comment: Looks promising. Actual code implementation would help a ton though!